# Snowflake Function GRANTS

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two schemas where number of functions created there. I wanted to grant function to ROLES.

Also wanted to FUTURE GRANT on functions to ROLES.

Do i need to create grant command for each functions. Also do we have future grants on functions?

Thanks
Ashok

Answer (score 2):

First, you can grant all on future functions.

```
grant all on future functions in schema "myDB"."mySchema" to role MyRole;
```

Then, you can generate the SQL to grant for existing functions:

```
show functions in schema "MyDB"."MySchema"; 
SELECT 'grant all on function "' || "name" || '" to role MyRole;' FROM  table(result_scan(last_query_id())) where "is_external_function" = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may more details here in Snowflake documentation:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html#
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html#future-grants-on-database-or-schema-objects